# Can I change from equal to not-equal in the same prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am trying to figure out how to create prepared statements. I have this now:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();

if($stmt->prepare("SELECT fk_player_id, player_draws, player_turn, player_passes, swapped FROM ".$prefix."_gameplayer WHERE fk_game_id = ? AND fk_player_id = ?")){

    $stmt->bind_param('ii', $currgame, $playerid);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($playerid, $udraws, $uturn, $upass, $uswaps);
    $stmt->fetch();

    // HERE I WANT TO MAKE A NEW CALL //

    $stmt->close(); 

}
```

In the area **// HERE I WANT TO MAKE A NEW CALL //** I want to run this:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT fk_player_id, player_tiles, player_draws, player_turn, player_passes, swapped FROM ".$prefix."_gameplayer WHERE fk_game_id = $currgame AND fk_player_id != $playerid");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

$opponent = $row['fk_player_id'];
$oppTiles = $row['player_tiles'];

$odraws = $row['player_draws']+1;
$oturn = $row['player_turn'];
$opass = $row['player_passes'];
$oswaps = $row['swapped'];
```

The ting is taht the 2 calls are identicly except the = and != . Can this be done in the same statement?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Not using the same statement, but if this is in an attempt to reduce an extra database query, you could just get all the results (leave out `fk_player_id` altogether) in the one statement and split the results manually.

Comment: Why are you using `mysql_*` functions in the second code part? They're deprecated and you didn't properly escape query parameters.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood your question, you need all players.
Well, select them all. You can separate at display time

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM {$prefix}_gameplayer WHERE fk_game_id = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();

$data = array();
if($stmt->prepare($sql)){
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $currgame);
    $stmt->execute();
    $res = $stmt->get_result();
    while ($ow = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    $stmt->close(); 
}
// to display own games
foreach ($data as $row) {
    if ($row['fk_player_id'] == $playerid) {
        // do something
    }
}
// to display other games
foreach ($data as $row) {
    if ($row['fk_player_id'] != $playerid) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, looks like the right solution except... I get an Server Error page when trying to run this. The error starts here: $res = $stmt->get_result(); Any ideas?

Comment: get_result is supported by not every build. So you have to get your data the way you did it before.

Comment: Sorry, new to prepared... You lost me. I then can't use the exapmle above?

Comment: I have really tried to figure the example out and are lost... Should I use the $stmt->bind_result() before get_result? Please help...

Comment: @YourCommonSense today i crossed need for `!=` how to use it in mysqli prepared statements?

Comment: @Ingus just use it

Comment: @YourCommonSense I made mistake. .. Sorry! Thanks for such a fast respond :D